# Leading Zero is dropped when converting a csv file to data table using oledb

Tags: c#, csv, oledb, jet

I have a csv file from which I have to populate different tables in database 
I am using Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0 to convert csv file to data table from where I proceed forward

the problem is when I do this a value such as "0261" is stored as 261, the leading zero is dropped, is there a way to prevent it???

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the value as a number, then there is no way to prevent it. All you can do is format the number in a report with leading zeros.

Another option is to store the number as four letter string (`char(4)`).

Comment: the data is not confined to a four letter string it may be as large as 10 digit

Comment: In that case, there is nothing you can do. Numbers in a database are always stored without leading zeros.

Comment: Or you can use `varchar(256)` :)

Comment: I found a solution just now I enclosed the number with double quotes after that it preserved 0s as it is now a string but the problem is it should be done where csv is genereated on which I dont have any control :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this site. http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/.

This will be easier to use and will give you your datatable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to preserve zeros as numbers using OleDb, so [I wrote my own class](http://utkarshpuranik.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/get-datatable-from-csv-without-oledb/) to avoid using OleDb and preserve zeros.

Comment: If his answer helped, wouldn't it be better to accept his answer?